# Coerce association matrix from vegdist() into a dataframe

Tags: r, vegan

I am using the `vegdist()` function in the **R package vegan** to generate an association matrix for a species abundance dataset (the association matrix produced is 936 by 936). I want to be able to **export/extract/coerce** this association matrix into a dataframe or format writeable as a **.csv** so that I can use it for subsequent analyses. I know you can use the output from `vegdist()` for things like ordination after, or visualize using heat maps (`coldiss()`), but in this case I want to actually be able to see and manipulate the raw association matrix.

Any ideas? I wasn't sure that sample data would really help in this case since it is such a large dataset.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about), [and show us what you have tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you own data set is to large to post, please have a look [here on how to make a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
write.csv(as.matrix(YOUR_MATRIX), "YOUR_MATRIX.csv")
```

Comment: Indeed, +1. `vegdist()` returns an object of class `"dist"`, which is a vector with attributes. The `as.matrix.dist()` S3 method coerces this to a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was just about to post a data example, when I saw your answer and it was exactly what I needed.